# Physical Android Back Button does not respond when coming from a selected list item

Tags: android, android-studio, back-button

My app has quite a few separate activity/fragment pairs, and relies on the Android universal back button for much of its navigation. This button works fine, EXCEPT when I'm trying to return from a DetailView activity back to a list of search results. 
Here's what the search results code looks like:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState) {

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.results_fragment, container, false);

ListView lv;
lv = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listViewResults);
lv.setAdapter(SearchResultsAdapter);
lv.setEmptyView(v.findViewById(R.id.emptyElement));
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
        ItemType selectedItem;
        selectedItem = (ItemType)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailViewActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(DetailViewFragment.RESULT_ID, resultIdNumber);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});

// ... some other stuff

   return v;
}
```

The *DetailView* is simply a collection of images and text.

The search returns expected results, and selecting the item shows the correct *DetailViewFragment*.

It seems like a very typical architecture, so I'm not sure why navigation back to the results page should be so problematic. I tried setting breakpoints to determine if the results activity ever restarted, but apparently it did not.

Comment: May I see the back button's code?

Comment: There is none; it's the physical Back button.

Comment: so what do you mean is, when we pressed the physical back button, the apps will exit?

Comment: @zuhrain, when the physical back button is pressed, nothing happens. The user has to navigate away from the activity by other means (such as the main menu).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make something when the back button is pressed, you have to override it:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     // code here 
    finish(); // to end activity: 
}
```

Comment: Okay. but why would I need to override to go back to a list view page when I don't need to override to return to any other page in the app?

Comment: It has quite a few features that are probably not relevant to this issue. Any particular part of the code you're interested in?

Comment: @BrogrammerDude maybe some widget or something is getting the back button action and it is what's stopping the activity to handle it and close it by itself.